# Build CalendarFX from github

Tags: java, javafx

Hello everyone I have downloaded CalendarFX from github and I'm trying to  build it to obtain the .JAR files but I haven't been able to make it work someone could help me? It would be very helpful thank you. Here is the link of the github repository: https://github.com/dlemmermann/CalendarFX#building-it

I'm using Eclipse by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directions on the Github repository are simply telling you to `install`, but it isn't explicity stated that you are supposed to do it with Maven. The `pom.xml` file (stands for Project Object Model) is fundamental to Maven projects.

Using command line, change directory to path of this project, then:

```
mvn install
```

... assumes you have [Maven installed](https://maven.apache.org/install.html).

Finally, as stated on the repository's readme:

> Once completed you will find the installation inside the target folder of the assembly module.

Comment: Solved, thank you mate.